# IE7 (I HATE IT) float issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a client who seems to use ie7, and is convinced that since he uses it, everyone else does (even tho its like .6% of users across the web) and there is one issue I just CANT FIX...

If anyone has ie7 and could help me, it would be so appreciated.

At the top of the page, there is a phone number in a blue box - it should float right, and on all browsers it does, besides ie7, and I just cant figure out why.

http://www.theadvancedsurgicalinstitute.com/

Comment: Go to http://modern.ie/ and download their IE7 VM for testing. That should help you. Alternatively, use http://browserstack.com/ (modern.ie is giving free subscriptions for browserstack too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to float the `div` that contains the `img` to the right:

```
<div id="clkcll" sizset="false" sizcache021125451562711411="22 23 67" style="float: right;">
```

I added it as an inline style, but you probably want to add the style to an external css file.

I'm not sure what the `sizeset` and `sizcache` attributes are.  They only seem to appear when I set the browser mode to IE7 in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Wow, that worked.. The div did have a float set in the css, but adding it like you did fixed it in ie7!

Comment: If you add `!important` to the css then you probably wouldn't need my inline style.  It would look something like `#clkcll { float: right !important; }`